# How to add a patterned shade (fill) (like diagonal strips or checker board etc.) within a table in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to add a patterned shade (fill) (like diagonal strips or checker board etc.) within a table in Word 2010?

If not - I guess the only way is to insert a shape and auto fit it to the cell size... Is there a way to auto fit the shape to a cell size permanently?

Thanks!

Comment: Auto-sizing images with cells will only work if your table cells have constant aspect ratio, otherwise e.g. a checkered or diagionally striped pattern will look ugly when stretched unisometrically.

Answer (score 1):

Select cell to shade -> right click: **Table Properties** -> 
**Borders & Shading** ->  **Shading** tab -> under **Patterns** -> select **Style**.

You can select the two colors of the binary patterns offered.
Make sure you only apply your style of choice to a cell and not the entire table (**Apply to** drop down menu).